# When does a method becomes part of a "BusinessLogic" and when it should be placed in "Repository"?

Tags: .net, architecture

- You have a 'method' in you hand.
- It hits the Db.
- It might be LOADING, SAVING, DELETING some entities according to method's implementation.

*And you need you place this method somewhere*; and your option is either the Repository or the Business Logic.

**Questions:**
What attributes of this method makes it part of the business logic so that you place it in the business-logic layer?

If I rephrase: How do you decide if a method should be placed to 'Business Logic' or to the 'Repository' ?

Comment: If it has business logic, it belongs there. If it only deals with the persistence layer, it belongs in the repository.

Comment: Downvoters, can you please tell why the question should be closed? Thanks

Comment: "How do you decide" == "Chatty, open-ended", as described in the FAQ. You are asking for opinions, which is not suitable for SO.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I bet the problem is that there isn't enough information.  It might help if you provided the method code.  Also, without knowing how your project is structured, it may be difficult to help you unless you're just asking a semi-hypothetical question.  I think the biggest key here is to remain consistent with the way the rest of your application is structured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your repository should **only** be doing simple CRUD operations (e.g. Insert, Select, Delete etc).  If it is doing more than that it belongs in Business Logic.

You can have a Service layer to do business logic which then calls out to your Repository but your repository should be 'dumb', doing just CRUD.

Comment: If it does _both_ it should be broken to parts each doing one.

Answer (score 1):

> - It hits the Db.

If the method accesses the database, whether executing SQL, querying from an O/R mapper or anything directly persistence-related, it should be in the persistence layer, not the business layer.

It might be in a Repository implementation, a DAO, you name it, but definitely a data access layer class.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Repository calls to be basic CRUD operations

Code that has business logic will be in b.logic layer
This layer can use the Repo calls to achieve what it is going after

An even better approach, that i have befitted from is seeing this as 3 layers

Workflow Or Transaction Script Layer
Business Logic Layer
Repository Layer

Workflow co ordinates between Repo calls and hands data to Business logic layer to perform
its task